# Spark -Python Not able to add values in a column

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I have created a RDD named Distance . All are float values. I intend to add them and find the total sum .

```
print(Distance.take(5))
Output : [802.0, 1055.0, 919.0, 204.0, 951.0]

print(sum(Distance.take(5)))
Output : 3931.0

totalDistance=Distance.reduce(lambda x,y:(x+y))
Output: Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-874f9e382e38> in <module>()
  2 # Reduce takes a function that acts on two elements and returns an object of same type.
  3 
----> 4 totalDistance=Distance.reduce(lambda x,y:(x+y))
```

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: Please post a [mcve], including full traceback.